# How to merge feature branch which is many commits behind master?

Tags: git

I'm quite new to git and I'm not sure if it's a dumb question.

Currently I'm working on feature_1 branch up to date with the master, and I want to merge it with feature_2 branch which is many commits behind the master.
What is the best way to do so?

My thought is to first checkout to feature_2 branch and merge with the master. Then checkout to feature_1 branch and merge with feature_2 branch?

Comment: Just do the merge; Git should be able to figure out that your version of the out of date features are the correct versions.

Comment: Are you asking which command will do the merge? Or are you asking what are the best practices?

Comment: "Merge with" is unclear. A merge is not a symmetrical operation, one branch is the receiving one and the other the source one. Please try to clearly describe which branch you want merged in which.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not merge a feature branch into another feature branch. Instead you should finish `feature_1` and merge it into `master`. Then just delete `feature_1`. Now when you continue work on `feature_2`, just merge `master` into it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to answer your question using an illustration showcasing what you are describing.

[image: Differences of merge operations]

It's important to understand that `merge` intertwines histories together, but just like [Romain Valeri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1057485/romain-valeri) mentions in his comment to your question, there's always a receiving end. In your case, either *feature-1* get's the changes present in *feature-2*, or *feature-2* gets all changes currently present in *feature-1*/*master*.

`HEAD` illustrates which branch is currently checked out, and in this case works as the receiving end when `merge` is invoked.

**A final note:** merging feature branches back-and-forth is generally bad practice. Try to keep them isolated and only integrate changes once they have been merged with `master` (or which ever branch you are using as your main branch). Once a branch has been merged into `master` it should generally be deleted.